# why listbox2 still empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

> I can not find where is the problem, when I put while loop as a comment it works,after while loop we can not read from sqldatareader more?
>   listbox2 still empty!

```
public partial class exTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "select employeeid,firstname,lastname from employees";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string item;
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            item =reader.GetString(1) + reader.GetString(2);
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
        ListBox2.DataSource = reader;
        ListBox2.DataValueField = "employeeId";
        ListBox2.DataTextField = "firstname";
        ListBox2.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the items from Reader to a List instead of setting the data source to the reader. I think the problem is that `reader` is an iterator, and you've already iterated over it once already, so by the time you set the source to the reader, it doesn't have any items left.

Comment: `ListBox2.DisplayMember = "firstname";
 ListBox2.ValueMember = "lastname";` try that.. also how could employeeId ever be a used when it's not part of your original Select query
`ListBox2.DataSource = reader;` should be set last

Comment: emloyeeid is part of query in string sql, Iam still confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `reader` again. 
From the [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

> Provides a way of reading a forward-only stream of rows from a SQL Server database.

You can read one row at a time, but you cannot go back to a row once you've read the next row.

What you have to do is you have to create a `list` of an object (e.g. `employee object`) that contains `employeeId`, `firstname`, `lastname`. Fill the list and assign it as a source for `list2` or something similar.